# JPA validation messages internationalization with Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, jpa, internationalization, thymeleaf

I've met with some issue I cannot solve. I would like to internatiolize JPA validation messages with Spring Thymeleaf.

I've tried a few solutions, but none of them works.

This is my entity class property:

```
@Length(min = 1, message = "#{field.empty}")
@Valid
private String lastName;
```

This is thymeleaf form:

```
<div class="form-group col">
    <label for="lastName" th:text="#{register.lastname}"></label>
    <input id="lastName" class="form-control" type="text"
        th:placeholder="#{register.lastname}"
        th:field="*{lastName}"
        th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('lastName')} ? is-invalid : ''"/>
    <small class="form-text text-danger"
        th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('lastName')}"
        th:errors="*{lastName}"></small>
</div>
```

I expect to print translated error message in the same way as you can see here

```
<label for="lastName" th:text="#{register.lastname}"></label>
```

But instead of seeing translated output, I can see #{field.empty}

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: I've encountered this one before, I can't test it currently but try removing the hashmark or the whole #{} from the Length annotation.

Comment: Oh, and you don't need @Valid on each field.

Comment: I've done this, but now I can see field.empty error. But I've done something else. For annotation Length I'd set Length property in messages.properties and I'd done same for NotEmpty, I'd set NotEmpty in properties and it worked for me well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So thanks to goalkicker Spring book (Chapter 8: Spring JSR 303 Bean validation) I'd dealt with my problem. You can set error messages in messages.property generic for annotation type and for specific class properties:

And for

```
@Length
```

use

```
Length=error message here.
```

For this specific field (lastName)

```
Length.lastName=error message here
```

The same can be used for all JPA annotations